# How to restore notification number badges on app icons on Samsung devices?

Tags: samsung, notifications, notification-badges

My Samsung Galaxy S22 stopped showing a number in the upper-left corner of the messages app when a new text message has arrived. I think these numbers have been called badges.

Is there a way to restore the number notification? Have they been eliminated for another method of notifications?

Answer (score 1):

Found path to restore icon badge numbers:  Settings > Notifications > Advanced > App icon badges > On